# How do I configure file upload buffering in Apache?

Tags: apache, file-upload, stream, http-proxy

I am uploading very large (gigabytes) files to an application server, with Apache as a proxy.

I want to stream process these to (1) use less memory and (2) prevent timeout from an AWS load balancer as I process the upload.

It seems that Apache does a substantial amount of buffering when I upload. If this is too much, I can't accomplish these objectives.

**What determines the amount of upload buffering, and how can I configure it?**

---

NOTE: To be clear, I am asking about Apache, not PHP.

Comment: How did you solve this?